# Android App monitoring incoming calls keeps phone awake

Tags: android, service, phone-state-listener

I have an android app that is monitoring incoming and outgoing calls. The app has a service, a PhoneStateListener, and to detect how long the call was sets a start time and end time. However, what I've noticed is that the phones screen starts to flash from bright to dim and back again. Now sure why, any idea's?

Comment: it is acquiring WakeLock.what do you want to do with that?

Comment: What do you mean it is acquiring WakeLock? Because of the user or because of the app?

Comment: Also I do not have WakeLock in my <uses-permission>

Comment: Because of the app. The app requests the phone to keep its CPU and Screen on instead of go to sleep.

Comment: it would be better if you can post some code.

Comment: @MehulJoisar There's no way for me to know what the relevant code is to post it.

Comment: @MehulJoisar Like i said,  I do not have WakeLock in my <uses-permission>. So how is it doing that?

Comment: I want my app to run all the time in the background but not interfere with the screens normal behavior

Comment: If you are not holding that permission than, it might be due to your cell. uninstall your app and check the behaviour again.

Comment: @MehulJoisar I wish that were the case :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although much can't be said without studying the code, your background service may acquire a wakelock to do the job .
If you are doing any background work in your code, You should modify your code to take full advantage of the wakelocks provided by android(like using "partial wakelock" "screen dim wakelock" "screen bright wakelock" )

This page should provide the relevant information on wakelock

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: Best practices for doing background jobs:

https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

Comment: Thank you, I've added the partial wakelock and I'm looking into those best practices. I do have a service that runs so that's done as should be, I only wonder about the insert into the database done there but thats not done until the call is ended not while its going on.